# What is smart identification in Quick Test Professional?

Tags: qtp

what is smart identification in Quick Test Professional?

Answer (score 3):

Smart identification is a fall back mechanism for when the description for the test object isn't good enough (matches multiple objects or none at all).

What happens is that if smart ID is enabled when the test is created (record/learn) then QTP stores some additional properties in the object repository and if the identification fails using the regular description it will attempt to use the properties in the smart ID.

One obvious difference between smart ID and regular description is that in regular description you have **mandatory** and **assistive** properties, when building the description QTP checks if the **mandatory** properties are enough in order to achieve uniqueness, if not the **assistive** properties are added one by one until uniqueness is achieved. Then only the properties that were used are saved in the description. Once the description is created all properties are equal if one differs the description doesn't match no matter if the mismatching property was originally defined as **mandatory** or **assistive**.

In Smart ID there are **base** and **optional** properties, all the **base** properties must match but the **optional** properties are treated differently.

1. If we haven't yet achieved uniqueness add the **optional** property
2. If with the property no  object matches the smart ID description remove it and go to the next **optional** property
3. If uniqueness is achieved stop otherwise smart ID failed

After running smart ID, if smart ID fails the behaviour depends on why we called it in the first place

- Multiple matches -- Use the ordinal selector
- No matches -- fail step

Note that starting in QTP 11 there is also the concept of VRI (Visual Relations Identification) which complicates issues a bit more...

Comment: Nice definition. You know your interview questions right! :D.

Comment: Thanks @AutomatedChaos, but you commented before I added most of the answer. You may not like it so much now...

Comment: Even better, it is a pain to explain the mechanism behind "regular description" and "smart ID", this makes it clear. (I used to be a teacher for the QTP Fundamentals course).  In my normal job, I do not use the Object Repository, just D.P. or with generic recognition functions as findTableWithText, clickButtonByText etc.